# Gazebo with GWSL: Opens and Closes

Tags: linux

Running Windows 10 (ver 21H1 19043.1415).

From the MS Store, OpenInWSL & GWSL were installed. These were tested and performed as expected.

Then also from MS Store, Ubuntu 20.04 was installed. Ubuntu started as expected. User and PW were entered. Ubuntu was updated and upgraded.

Then GIMP was installed from Ubuntu terminal.  GIMP started and ran as expected. In the GWSL app, GIMP was listed as a Linux App.  GIPM starts and runs from the Linux App list in GWLS. When started, GIMP runs in X server running on localhost: 0.0

Gazebo was installed per the "one liner" instructions at the following website:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install

```
curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
```

The Gazebo installed without apparent errors.  Gazebo did NOT get added to GWSL's Linux Apps where GIMP is listed.

When Gazebo is run, the Gazebo start image briefly displays in X server running on localhost: 0.0. Then Gazebo closes before the app can fully start.

Some assistance would be greatly appreciated with getting Gazebo to fully start running in this environment.

[image]

Comment: What colour is the gazebo? What is it doing? Is it a dread gazebo? (probably is, if it encourages brawndo-installer)

Comment: The color is orange.  It says: GAZEBO in large font, and below it says, Simulation made easy.  Above GAZEBO is wireframe cube.  And partially visible below says Preparing your world.  I have a snip copy of the image.

Comment: sorry, my comment was a [joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_and_the_Dread_Gazebo).  except for the bit about brawndo-installer, that part was 100% serious.

Comment: In general, though, don't expect software installed or run with WSL to work 100% smoothly all the time.  Just as Linux users have to jump through hoops sometimes to get MS Windows software to run with WINE, Windows users will have their own weird hoops to jump through with WSL.   I'm not entirely sure if your question is on-topic here or not (WSL stuff is a grey area, depending on the question), but you would certainly get more & better answers from people who actually use Windows & WSL, which isn't anywhere near as common here on U&L as it is on, say, https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Gazebo finally works in Windows 10, WSL2.**

It really can be done.  Two solid days of focused efforts ultimately proved a successful effort.

Best two sources of information:

http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DW7l9LHdK5c

[image]